# GAM - factor smooth and main effects for both variables?

Tags: r, interaction, nonlinear-regression, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am working with data on `cuteness` judgements and `size` judgments for differently named fantasy creatures. The interesting part of the different names are the `vowel`s contained in them.

The question I am fitting a GAM for is: Do the effects of `cuteness` and `vowel` interact when it comes to `size` judgements?

Thus far, my model looks like this:

```
mdl1 <- gam(size ~ 
                s(cuteness, bs = "bs", by = vowel, k = 5),
                data = data)
```

The interaction of `cuteness` and `vowel` reaches significance for some of the vowels (which is fine).

Now a reviewer asked to modify the model so that not only the interaction effects of `cuteness` and `vowel` are contained but also the individual main effects of both `cuteness` and `vowel`, e.g. like this:

```
mdl2 <- gam(size ~ 
                s(cuteness, bs = "bs", by = vowel, k = 5) +
                cuteness +
                vowel,
                data = data)
```

As I have not worked with interactions in GAMs before, I am at a loss when it comes to deciding whether such a model structure is valid / makes sense (from a statistical point of view). Hence, my question: Is such a model structure valid, does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original model was incorrectly specified; it should have been

```r
mdl1 <- gam(size ~ vowel +
                s(cuteness, bs = "bs", by = vowel, k = 5),
                data = data, method = "REML", family = ...)
```

Where beyond some technical things — `method` and choosing an appropriate `family` for `size` (is it really conditionally Gaussian? 0 or negative `size` values don't make immediate sense to me and if so that might preclude using `family = gaussian()`) — note that I have included the mean response for each vowel through the parametric factor term. You could replace this with `s(vowel, bs = "re")` instead.

With that specification you have the main effect for the `vowel` means but there is no average effect for `cuteness`, which is what I presume the reviewer means by "main effect". To specify that model, I would suggest using the new-ish `"sz"` basis:

```r
mdl1 <- gam(size ~
                s(cuteness, bs = "bs", k = 5) +
                s(cuteness, vowel, bs = "sz", k = 5,
                  xt = list(bs = "bs")),
                data = data, method = "REML", family = ...)
```

With this basis, you **don't** need the explicit parametric term for the group means; those are included in the `"sz"` basis, as deviations from the overall mean of the response (the model constant / Intercept term).

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to check for which vowels the interaction of `cuteness` and `vowel` reaches significance? The interaction overall clearly reaches significance (`p<2e-16` for `s(cuteness,vowel)`).

Comment: I think you'd need to do this with post-hoc tests, just like you would for a linear model - you need to predict from the model or combine terms as you want to test for contrasts involving the two smooths. The general idea is in `gratia::difference_smooths()` for example, but it doesn't know yet how to work with these `sz` basis smooths where we want the "main" effect smooth plus pairs of smooths created by `sz`. The general idea is also discussed here: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/10/10/difference-splines-i/ but only for factor by smooths; the math is the same however